# Get last row of same value in a column

Tags: vba, excel

If I have a column with a date of 5-10-2016, and its from row 3 to 23.  What is the best way get the last row number of the same value (5-10-2016).  The date will always change, and the number of rows will also be different.  Thanks!
Jim

Comment: are the dates sorted?

Comment: Hi Scott, They are.  But I'm not sure if that will always be the case.

Comment: Use Application.Match() to find the first row then iterate from there till it no longer is equal.  You will want to test if the match finds anything before looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start finding it from last row

```
Sub FindLastRow()

Dim dt as Date, i as Long, wk As worksheet

Set wk = sheet1

dt = wk.Range("B1").value2

For i= wk.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row to 2 Step -1
      if wk.Range("B" & i).Value2 = dt then
         msgbox "Last Row with Date :" & dt & " is " & i
         Exit Sub
      End if
Next i

Msgbox "Date Not Found"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Newguy. But I will not know what the date will be, And I won't know how many rows a date will take,  The only thing I know it will always be in Column "B".

Comment: @user3641694 if you do not know the date how will you find the last occurrence of said date?

Comment: Where are you getting the date from cell , textbox or something else ?

Comment: The date is coming from a cell. Scott - That is my problem.  How can I read a value from a particular cell. If I can  write something like, FIRSTDATE = READ VALUE of B-1, then loop through the B cells until the value changes, say at row 10.  The I know row 1 to 9 has the same date, and that would be my ALLROWS for that particular value.  I'm doing this because I need to find duplicate values, but only where the date is the same. Thanks!

Comment: to assign value to variable from a cell use `=` like if `dt = Cells( row , column )` so for B1 row is 1 and col = 2 hence `dt = Cells( 1, 2).Value2`